# How to get chosen option value when mouse over drop list option?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-chosen

Im use [chosen jquery plugin](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/options.html)
 to select image option ! also when change trigger i get a value is easy , so now i wanna get value when mouseover/hover an option in select dropdown like image below to show in preview div[image] ! can i do this ? thank any help !

my code to get change trigger

```
    $('#patterns').chosen({ disable_search_threshold: 5 }).on('change',function(){
    if(!($(this).val() == 'none')){
        $('#pattern-preview').css('background-image', 'url(<?php echo $patterns_fulldir;?>' + $(this).val() + ')');
    }else{
        $('#pattern-preview').css('background-image', '');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Not familiar with chosen. However, to me it looks like you should be looking at the `hover` event, rather than `change` event as this on' fires when you click the entry. your revision might look like this:

```
$('#patterns').chosen({ disable_search_threshold: 5 }).on('hover',function(e){
    var $target = $(e.target); // you may have to use $target, rather than $(this)
    if(!($target.val() == 'none')){
        $('#pattern-preview').css('background-image', 'url(<?php echo $patterns_fulldir;?>' + $target.val() + ')');
    }else{
        $('#pattern-preview').css('background-image', '');
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks jim ! i has try and dont work , maybe chosen dose not support hover event ?

Comment: sorry about that, that was my best shot in the absence of more knowledge on chosen. will see if i can look up the dev's api ref on supported events

Comment: alas, i can't see anything further having looked at the link you supplied in the OP. will come back if i have any eureka moments. in th emenatime, hope you get th eissue solved quickly and easily.